# Create struct in one function to be used in another

Tags: go

I am new to Golang and still trying to get my head around structs. I can't seem to figure out how to and create it in one function and use it in another.

Here is my code.

File 1 main.go

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/asolopovas/docker_valet/modules"
    "fmt"
)
func main { 
   fl := dockervalet.GetFlags()
   fmt.Pringln(fl.user) // returns fl.user undefined 
}
```

File 2 flags.go

```
package dockervalet

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
)

type Flags struct {
    user     string
}

func GetFlags() Flags {
    var userFlag string
    flag.StringVar(&userFlag, "u", "", "")
    flag.StringVar(&userFlag, "user", "", "")
    flag.Parse()

    fl := Flags{
       user: userFlag,
    }

    fmt.Println(fl.user) // works as expected

    return fl

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Structs defined within functions _cannot_ be shared with other functions. They must be defined at the package level. But your code doesn't show you doing either of those things. So I really have no idea what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I figured it out. The problem wash that I had to use First Capital letters to be able to access this return struct in another function.

File 1 main.go

```
func main { 
   fl := GetFlags()
   fmt.Pringln(fl.User)
}
```

File 2 flags.go

```
type Flags struct {
    User     string
}

func GetFlags() Flags {
    var userFlag string
    flag.StringVar(&userFlag, "u", "", "")
    flag.StringVar(&userFlag, "user", "", "")
    flag.Parse()

    fl := Flags{
       User: userFlag,
    }

    fmt.Println(fl.user) // works as expected

    return fl

}
```